# Clustering of points from a set of 3D points based on point density using python

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have a set of around 300 points in three-dimension. But the density of points is not uniform throughout.How do I break it into clusters based on the density of neighborhood points?

Answer (score 0):

k-means clustering is a good point to start with. K-means algorithm clusters the data points based on euclidean distance from one point to another.

[scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) has k-means implementation

Comment: It's not working the way I want it to. It is clustering based on Euclidean distance. But I want clustering based on point density.

Comment: @Sourav: do you mean, each point has a density feature or the density of the distribution of the points in the vector space.

Comment: No, points don't have any density feature. I'm talking about the density of distribution.

Comment: Euclidean distance among points is mathemaical term for describing the distribution of points. higher density -> closer points -> lesser euclidean distance

Comment: As far as I understand, this algorithm takes Euclidean distance from a commom point. How am I supposed to measure density from that?